# Create a backup from an account other than postgres

Tags: backup, postgresql

I am trying to back up a server securely. To do that, I have made a user on the database with read-only access strictly for the purpose of backing up using `pg_dumpall`.

It seems however, my profile does not have access to `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall` but it does have access to `psql`. As such I am forced to `sudo su - postgres` to run `pg_dump`. However, this seems tacky to me. If I am already sudo'd into the root user for the database there's no point in having a separate backup profile because I can just run `pg_dumpall` directly.

Is there a way to accomplish this? My idea was something like:

`pg_dumpall -f mybackup.bak -U backup` and have a `.pgpass` in my user's home directory so it can be run automatically.

For reference I am running CentOS 7 with PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to to be to run `sudo yum install postgresql95-devel` to get the tools to do the backup.

I will accept this an answer in two days when it allows me to.